# What kind of test do I need to test a network issue on a few specific devices

Tags: android, junit, mockito, okhttp

How can I test to make sure request timeout is respected

I need to write a test that shows that when a okhttp request takes longer than the timeout period specified, it gets canceled. I am using junit4 and mockito. I am finding it a bit difficult to write a unit test for this because it depends on the device's internet connection

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to run the test on a device or emulator

See example android tests here https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/android-test

```
$ ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/myusername/Library/Android/sdk ./gradlew :android-test:connectedCheck
...
> Task :android-test:connectedDebugAndroidTest
...
11:55:40 V/InstrumentationResultParser: Time: 13.271
11:55:40 V/InstrumentationResultParser:
11:55:40 V/InstrumentationResultParser: OK (12 tests)
...
11:55:40 I/XmlResultReporter: XML test result file generated at /Users/myusername/workspace/okhttp/android-test/build/outputs/androidTest-results/connected/TEST-pixel3a-Q(AVD) - 10-android-test-.xml. Total tests 13, passed 11, assumption_failure 1, ignored 1,
...
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1m 30s
63 actionable tasks: 61 executed, 2 up-to-date
```

You could start by modifying https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/android-test/src/androidTest/java/okhttp/android/test/compare/OkHttpClientTest.kt

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class OkHttpClientTest {
  private var client = OkHttpClient()

  @Test fun get() {
    val request = Request.Builder()
        .url("https://google.com/robots.txt")
        .build()
    client.newCall(request).execute().use { response ->
      assertThat(response.code).isEqualTo(200)
      assertThat(response.protocol).isEqualTo(Protocol.HTTP_2)
    }
  }
}
```